# Recover partitions Mac OS internal HD

Tags: partition, macos, gparted, testdisk, gdisk

I booted to a live Ubuntu USB, wanting to delete partitions on an SD card, and ended up deleting all my partitions on my MacBook Pro's internal HD.

I have already tried `gpart` (which gets stuck at "Begin scan...") and `testdisk` (which can't create partitions since "Function write_part_mac not implemented"!).

I did try <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> at boot, but gave it up as it was taking a long time. I thought there would be an easier and faster alternative.

Is there a way to recover data with partitions on my hd?

Here's my `testdisk` output for the Mac HD:

```
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
> P DOS_FAT_32                    40     409639     409600 [EFI]

> P HFS                       409640  489972567  489562928
```

Comment: Try using `gdisk` `x extra functionality (experts only)`, then within the expert menu `b use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)`. If you have a second metadata copy then you should be able to rebuild the partition table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel MacBook Pro's use GUID partition table for disk partitioning which one can edit with `gdisk`.

A copy of the partition table metadata is usually stored as backup of the primary. You can read more detail about it on the Arch Wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#About_the_GUID_Partition_Table)

You need first to know the device name, `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` of your Mac disk.
You can use the `blkid`, `lsblk` or `dmesg` commands to determine the exact name if you do not know.

From your Ubuntu Live USB, use `gdisk /dev/sdX` (where X is your device name)

e.g. /dev/sdb (assuming the USB is given sda and the Mac is the only other disk)

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): `r`

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): `b` 

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): `w`
```

And reboot

The `b` restores the backup GUID partition table and `w` **writes it to disk**

You way wish to also run the `v` *verify* after restoring the backup table and before writing it to the disk. `gdisk` is very sane about letting one create and modify the partition table, in memory, and nothing is written on disk until you write it with the `w` command. Be very sure you are happy with the recovery result before you write it to disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did as you said. But I don't see any partitions when I run 'v'. I had tried apple's internet recovery some time back. Is it possible that the internet recovery messed up the partition table meta data backup?

Comment: `p` shows the partition table, `v` simply verifies the table and hopefully prints "No problems found."